# Entity Framework workaround for query based on combination of primitives in memory

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a class T:

```
class T {
   int Prop1Id;
   int Prop2Id;
}
```

At runtime, in memory, I have:

```
var L1 = new List<T>();
```

And L1 contains the following T objects:

```
Prop1   Prop2
12       5
6        7
8        9
10       12
```

I **cannot** do the following:

```
attributes.Where(x=>L1.Any(y=>y.Prop1ID == x.Prop1ID && y.Prop2ID == x.Prop2ID))
```

`attributes` is an EF type (i.e: in the DB)

This does not work because it cannot create a constant value type of T - it expects only primitives and enumerables.

Has anyone figured out a workaround other than bring back all of attributes so they are in memory as IEnumerable instead of IQueryable? For me, that's not really an option :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose with what you provided, the 2 properties are of ***integer*** type. So you can try this work-around. We need to convert your list into another list of string keys like this:

```
var stringKeys = L1.Select(e => e.Prop1 + "_" + e.Prop2);
//then use stringKeys normally
attributes.Where(x=> stringKeys.Contains(x.Prop1ID + "_" + x.Prop2ID));
```

If it's not the case (not limited to integer properties), we may have to do it in a more complicated way by building the Where conditions based on the list `L1`:

```
var result = attributes;
foreach(var e in L1){
  var k1 = e.Prop1;
  var k2 = e.Prop2;
  var sub = attributes.Where(x => k1 == x.Prop1ID && k2 == x.Prop2ID);      
  result = result.Concat(sub);
}
//then access result instead of attributes
```

The above approach may be a bit less efficient. It will execute `L1.Count`times of `WHERE` against the database table before concatenating (`UNION ALL`) all results. However I believe if it's performed on key columns, the performance is still good.

The last solution is try using Expression tree (representing the predicate passed in `Where`):

```
//suppose your attributes is a set of Attribute
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Attribute));
var p1 = Expression.Property(p, "Prop1ID");
var p2 = Expression.Property(p, "Prop2ID");
var initBool = Expression.Constant(false) as Expression;
//build the BodyExpression for the predicate
var body = L1.Aggregate(initBool, (c,e) => {
               var ep1 = Expression.Constant(e.Prop1);
               var ep2 = Expression.Constant(e.Prop2);
               var and = Expression.And(Expression.Equal(ep1, p1), Expression.Equal(ep2,p2));
               return Expression.Or(c, and); 
           });
attributes.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<Attribute, bool>>(body, p));
```

Note that the type of `x.Prop1ID` should exactly match the type of each element of `L1.Prop1` (such as should be both `int` or `float`, ...). The same condition applies to all corresponding properties. Otherwise you need to modify the code to build the Expression tree (the reason here is `Expression.Equal` requires the 2 operand expressions to have the same data type). I've not tested the last code using Expression tree but it's very clear on the idea.

The last option involving Expression (internally) is try using `LinqKit`. I've not even used this library once but it can help you be free from building Expression tree in many cases. So give it a try if it can help you run your original query without getting the exception you mentioned.